# At what speed would an average adult human male bleed out, if their arm was amputated?

Tags: blood, blood-circulation, amputation

I'm not sure what unit of measurement to ask this question in, but I suppose that pints per second would be the right way to think of things. Currently writing a short story and i'd like to add some graphic medical accuracy.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. This is an interesting question, but there is a good deal of variability. It may help to add some detail about the situation you're writing about (e.g., mechanism of injury, available first aid). Personally, I couldn't give you a direct answer without some digging into the literature. Generally, the mortality for traumatic amputation of the arm isn't particularly high, but the data are from patients who receive field treatment. A traumatic leg amputation or even simply a femoral fracture would be a different story.

Comment: As @DeNovo points out, bleeding out isn't assured. True anecdote: A local guy was back in the woods behind his house using a log splitter to split firewood. Somehow he managed to completely sever his arm at mid-forearm. He picked up the severed arm, calmly walked several hundred meters back to his house, and called 911. EMS arrived to find him sitting on his front porch with his arm in hand. Bleeding was minimal, presumably because the severed arteries spasmed and largely sealed themselves off. Bleeding remained minimal during a 30 minute transport and the arm was successfully reattached.

Comment: @CareyGregory Is definitely correct! It also depends on how the limb is amputated. If I recall correctly, a clean cut is far more like to bleed heavily than a crushing injury.

Answer (score 2):

Rate of blood loss through amputation of an arm will depend on a range of things including initial blood pressure and heart rate of the patient etc. Plus, blood pressure falls as the amount of fluid left in the blood vessels becomes insufficient ([Merck MSD Manual, 2019](https://www.msdmanuals.com/en-gb/home/blood-disorders/anemia/anemia-due-to-excessive-bleeding)).

How the arm is severed can be a factor too.  Some actions can seal the blood vessels at the ends through heat of the blade, cutting action etc.

However, because heart rate is a factor and increased heart rate due to fear for example would cause faster blood loss, to give a idea, arm blood flow at rest and during arm exercise was measured by [Ahlborg & Jensen-Urstad (1991)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2022586).

> Eight subjects performed continuous 30-min arm exercises with an increase in intensity every 10 min (30, 60, and 90 W).
>
> **[...]**
>
> Total arm blood flow was calculated to be 0.21 +/- 0.04 l/min at rest and 2.43 +/- 0.14 l/min at 90 W.

To convert these figures to US Pints per minute, multiply the figures by 2.11 making the figures

- between 0.34 and 0.54 US Pints/min at rest, and
- between 4.84 and 5.44 US Pints/min at 90 W.

### References

Ahlborg, G., & Jensen-Urstad, M. (1991). Arm blood flow at rest and during arm exercise. *Journal of Applied Physiology, 70*(2), 928-933. doi: [10.1152/jappl.1991.70.2.928](https://doi.org/10.1152/jappl.1991.70.2.928) pmid: [2022586](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2022586)

Comment: I don't think you can use blood flow figures during exercise to answer this question. Trauma brings a whole host of other factors into account, such as decreasing BP due to volume loss as you mentioned.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I introduced blood flow figures during exercise to try to factor in the fact that fear of possible death would raise heart rate which therefore would increase blood loss.  As we both pointed out, the rate of blood loss would differ depending on a number of factors including blood pressure, heart rate and as now pointed out, whether they remain calm or not.

Comment: @ChrisRogers it's more than whether they remain calm or not. Injury to the vascular tree causes a series of physiologic responses to prevent blood loss, including vasospasm and the coagulation cascade. Those strategies aren't going to prevent blood loss from, e.g., the axillary artery, but they will make it take longer. Your flow figures, suggest the arm receives 4-5% of the total cardiac output. That's useful information, to be sure, but I wouldn't use that to predict time to exsanguination.